# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/img/glyphicons-halflings.png"): only in Chrome in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome

I have an issue I have never encountered in a Rails app. This is an existing project (Rails 4.0.4 app) I have been working on for over a year and this issue just popped up out of the blue (I didn't change any code).

When I run the app locally (in development) I get the error: `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/img/glyphicons-halflings.png"):` Here is [the entire console error](https://gist.github.com/marklocklear/5c33cdfe48ea36ffaa3bf3879a9df509).

Firefox and Safari are fine (I don't see the error there). Also, what I am seeing in the browser is the app looks to be a responsive/mobile display. Also, in production, Chrome is fine.

The only thing I can come up with that might have changed was that I did install a new RVM Ruby, and I think I may have updated RVM in the process, but I don't see how that could/would affect anything here.

Comment: Indeed I do think this is an RVM issue. I have noticed that from time to time I am prompted to allow ruby to run (security pop up in mac) and when that happens, that is when I see this error. I am wondering if this is a security/signature issue with rvm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an rvm issue. I solved this by uninstalling/reinstalling the rvm ruby version and gemset.